# How to filter post via categories selected by a user input?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to filter a custom post type based on a users selection. Eg the user chooses a category from a input select and the list of posts dynamically updates.

How do I go about achieving this?

Here is my WP_Query to load the posts

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'careers',

);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($posts->have_posts()) : 
    while($posts->have_posts()) : 
        $posts->the_post();

        echo '<div class="otherrow"><div class="otherpostion"><h3>', 
        the_field('position'), 
        '</h3><p>', 
        the_field('brief'),
        '</p></div><div class="othercontract"><h3>', 
        the_field('contract'),
        '</h3></div><div class="otherdate"></h3>', 
        the_date('d / m / y', '<h3>', '</h3>'),
           '</h3></div><div class="otherlink"><h3><a href="',
           the_permalink(),
           '" >VIEW JOB</a></h3></div></div> ';


       endwhile;
   endif;
```

?>
The Category I would like to filter is 'locations', eg "location1' and 'location2'. I have already set this up and have pages only showing single locations but the home page needs to let the user filter the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you assigned any role to a user like author / Editor?

This one basic user only with subscriber role. Please write more so easy to understand whats you wants

Answer (score 0):

Please use [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) with custom Taxonomy parameter on dropdown change event :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: He wants it dynamic - meaning the 'bob' is the variable - he could use either POST or GET to set and retrieve the variable - but then it will be submitted - else he should probably do it with AJAX

Comment: You can use like:
'terms' => $_POST['field_name']